# Proof strategy for simple proofs.

Tags: logic

I'm currently in a discrete mathematics course and I'm having quite a bit of trouble with the idea of proofs. From what I understand the one I've been stuck on is also rather simple but to me it's very difficult to wrap my head around how I prove something without just showing an example where it is true. The proof in question goes as follows:

> Prove that $mn < 0$ if and only if $m > 0$ and $n < 0$ or $m < 0$ and $n > 0$.

I've determined that if m & n are both positive then mn > 0 and that if m & n are negative then (-m)(-n) > 0. At this point however I'm really not sure where to take the rest of the proof... 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For one direction, suppose $mn < 0$.

- If $n > 0$, then dividing both sides of $mn < 0$ by $n$ does not change the inequality and gives $m < 0$.
- If $m > 0$, then dividing both sides of $mn < 0$ by $m$ does not change the inequality and gives $n < 0$.

For the other direction:

- Suppose $m > 0$. Assume that $n > 0$. Then $mn > 0$, a contradiction. We must have $n < 0$ to obtain $mn < 0$.
- Suppose $n > 0$. Assume that $m > 0$. Then $mn > 0$, a contradiction. We must have $m < 0$ to obtain $mn < 0$.

Comment: So would this work for then entire proof? Or just a section of it? I seem to understand it for the most part but does this fully prove to original proof?

Comment: @JohnathanScott no, because you have to prove both that if $mn < 0$ then $m > 0$ and $n < 0$ or $m < 0$ and $n > 0$, and that if $m > 0$ and $n < 0$ or $m < 0$ and $n > 0$ then $mn < 0$. This is the meaning of the statement "if and only if". The answer given here has shown you the "only if" part, and the "if" part is still missing.

Comment: @JohnathanScott I have edited my answer to include both directions, so this will answer fully your question. But if this is your homework, please only use my answer as a guide, and write your proof in your own words.

Comment: @dragon : Should we also consider the case where $n$ is $0$ in the method of contradiction?

Comment: @Nighty, Yes.  $0$ is a possible case for $n$, also for $m$.